# Does Linksys E4200 router support FAT32?

Tags: router

I plugged in a FAT32 drive but it would not recognize it. It seems a drive but would not mount it or give me option to do so.

Do I need to install DD-WRT or TomatoeUSB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should, Have you followed all the steps listed here? 
 http://www6.nohold.net/Cisco2/ukp.aspx?pid=80&app=vw&vw=1&login=1&json=1&docid=0868d4e24a6a468280c3cf270c1d6a31_21517.xml 
You must not only add the drive but create a share. If you have problems with the preceding instructions please list the exact step that it fails at. Also, make sure that you have the most up to date firmware from linksys.

Comment: Thanks so much for the link! BTW, anyone install TomatoUSB or DD_WRT with E4200?